# AJAX unable to open request to target file

Tags: php, ajax, forms, submit

I have an image that calls a javascript onclick. after validation I call a target file that adds the record to database and returns. My code looks like this

.....

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","addrecord.php?iddesc=gold&tid=t_id&pid=p_id",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

after inserting the record it returns echo "insert done"; 
and my code above the xmlhttp.open () is like this

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                    //alert("id is "+id);
                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
```

When I execute this code on the browser, js gets called. I have alerts in all places and I am able to track the code flow until xmlhttp.open(); but nothing happens. I am able to call the target php file independent through other test programs.

Comment: Is addrecord.php in the same folder as the file you are running this script from?

Comment: have you confirmed that the ajax hit actually reaches the server? does a GET show up in the access log?

Comment: CassieCarter yes the files are in the same directory.
MarcB When I check the access logs, I see a GET call to calling php file and not the target php file. is that what you were asking?

Comment: An AJAX request/response sample that I had working is not working anymore. I am not sure what is causing this. The only thing that I can think of as a change since the time I had the sample AJAX working is, I installed Symfony2 to play around. Wondering if that is causing any conflict.

Comment: Anyone? I guess I would like to know if installing symfony2 messes up previous installations of xmlhttp request/response through standalone php codes?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out that this was being caused by a href reference on the anchor within which my images are positioned. When I remove the href I am able to access ajax GET or POST.

Now I have to figure out how to have href and ajax. I am sure there has to be a way.

Not sure why href is taking precedence over ajax's xmlhttp.request().